# Background image is not showing up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm developing a sub page for my website. I have a nav bar and footer. I just want to add a background image behind the nav bar just like this.

[image]

I tried ..

```
<div class="seo-content"></div>

.seo-content{
  background: url("/images/ss.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

But It's not working as expected.

Now it showing like this way ..

[image]

If I add height property, it showing up. But I need to sketch actual image size to the screen. That's why I used background-size: cover;

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `url(images/ss.jpg)` or `url(../images/ss.jpg)` but ultimately it depends upon your file structure.

Comment: I tried, looks like that's not a image path problem.

Comment: @Cssy, provide width and height for that div , to see the background image -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aZpjvo

Answer (score 1):

Is the div possibly a child of a floating div container?
If it's the child of a floating div or enclosing element it would have zero height thus not showing the image.

Try inspect element to gain a bit more detail?

Comment: That's the main div of that section. But that div wrapped with section element and section has no styles.

Answer (score 0):

Use to following code:

```
 .seo-content {
   background: url("w3schools.com/css/bgdesert.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 0;
 }
```

Comment: @CssSY It shouldn't. This answer is completely wrong. It has the same effect as your code.

Comment: @CssSY, please try with relative url - ("./images/ss.jpg")

Comment: This answer does nothing. `background` is the master css property and encompasses `background-image`. This does nothing different from the code in the question. Changing the path won't do anything either.

Comment: From the code in the post , i see that the background image is available , but due to div width and height , it is not showing up, try increasing width and height of div - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aZpjvo

Comment: @CssSY, if you remove the width and height , you will not see background image .Try adding width and height you will find the background

Comment: I don't want to give height or width. I need to sketch it to the actual size of image.

Comment: @Cssy  Use width and height 100% with position:fixed 
.seo-content{
  background: url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/bgdesert.jpg");
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;  
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 0;
}

Comment: @CssSY any luck ??

Comment: Working fine now! Thanks

Comment: Thanks @CssSY if my answered helped your question, please mark my answer as answered and vote if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a fixed hight:

```
.seo-content{
  background: url("/images/ss.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
}
```